# how to toggle expand row by click on button in table using bootstrap and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this example, I've successfully made table to be collapse but it is only click row in the `table`.

I wanna to change it , only if click on button the expand more datails

**[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w7L3cgmx/)**

### Code Snippet

```js
$('.flip').click(function() {
  $(this)
    .closest('tbody')
    .next('.section')
    .toggle('slow');
});
```

```css
.section {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="main_table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="firstline">
      <th>CASINO</th>
      <th>BONUS</th>
      <th>HIGHLIGHTS</th>
      <th>DEPOSIT</th>
      <th>RATING</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" class="flip">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/logosquare-big.png" /><button>PLAY NOW!</button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>200% UP TO</div>
              <div>$1000</div>
              <div>+250 FREE SPINS</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                </li>
              </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
              <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-nodeposit.png" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button id="acc1">READ MORE <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="section">
    <tr>
      <td>item 111</td>
      <td>item 112</td>
      <td>item 113</td>
      <td>item 114</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item 121</td>
      <td>item 122</td>
      <td>item 123</td>
      <td>item 124</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item 131</td>
      <td>item 132</td>
      <td>item 133</td>
      <td>item 134</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" class="flip">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/logosquare-big.png" /><button>PLAY NOW!</button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>200% UP TO</div>
              <div>$1000</div>
              <div>+250 FREE SPINS</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                </li>
              </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
              <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-nodeposit.png" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star-half fa-2x"
                aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button id="acc1">READ MORE <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="section">
    <tr>
      <td>item 211</td>
      <td>item 212</td>
      <td>item 213</td>
      <td>item 214</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item 221</td>
      <td>item 222</td>
      <td>item 223</td>
      <td>item 224</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item 231</td>
      <td>item 232</td>
      <td>item 233</td>
      <td>item 234</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" class="flip">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/logosquare-big.png" /><button>PLAY NOW!</button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>200% UP TO</div>
              <div>$1000</div>
              <div>+250 FREE SPINS</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                </li>
              </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
              <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-nodeposit.png" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button id="acc1">READ MORE <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="section">
    <tr>
      <td>item 311</td>
      <td>item 312</td>
      <td>item 313</td>
      <td>item 314</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item 321</td>
      <td>item 322</td>
      <td>item 323</td>
      <td>item 324</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item 331</td>
      <td>item 332</td>
      <td>item 333</td>
      <td>item 334</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" class="flip">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/logosquare-big.png" /><button>PLAY NOW!</button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>200% UP TO</div>
              <div>$1000</div>
              <div>+250 FREE SPINS</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                </li>
              </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
              <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-deposit.png" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star-half fa-2x"
                aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button id="acc1">READ MORE <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="section">
    <tr>
      <td>item 311</td>
      <td>item 312</td>
      <td>item 313</td>
      <td>item 314</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item 321</td>
      <td>item 322</td>
      <td>item 323</td>
      <td>item 324</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item 331</td>
      <td>item 332</td>
      <td>item 333</td>
      <td>item 334</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" class="flip">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/logosquare-big.png" /><button>PLAY NOW!</button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>200% UP TO</div>
              <div>$1000</div>
              <div>+250 FREE SPINS</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                </li>
              </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
              <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-nodeposit.png" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button id="acc1">READ MORE <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="section">
    <tr>
      <td>item 311</td>
      <td>item 312</td>
      <td>item 313</td>
      <td>item 314</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item 321</td>
      <td>item 322</td>
      <td>item 323</td>
      <td>item 324</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item 331</td>
      <td>item 332</td>
      <td>item 333</td>
      <td>item 334</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

if can get class flip from td to button read more

Comment: my answer is worked for you or not ? still any doubt ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('.readmore').click(function () {
            $(this).closest('table').closest('tbody').next('.section').toggle('slow');
        });
```

```css
.section {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="main_table">
        <thead>
            <tr class="firstline">
                <th>CASINO</th>
                <th>BONUS</th>
                <th>HIGHLIGHTS</th>
                <th>DEPOSIT</th>
                <th>RATING</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6" class="flip">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/logosquare-big.png" /><button>PLAY NOW!</button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div>200% UP TO</div>
                                <div>$1000</div>
                                <div>+250 FREE SPINS</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-nodeposit.png" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="readmore" id="acc1">READ MORE <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="section">
            <tr>
                <td>item 111</td>
                <td>item 112</td>
                <td>item 113</td>
                <td>item 114</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>item 121</td>
                <td>item 122</td>
                <td>item 123</td>
                <td>item 124</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>item 131</td>
                <td>item 132</td>
                <td>item 133</td>
                <td>item 134</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6" class="flip">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/logosquare-big.png" /><button>PLAY NOW!</button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div>200% UP TO</div>
                                <div>$1000</div>
                                <div>+250 FREE SPINS</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-nodeposit.png" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star-half fa-2x"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="readmore" id="acc1">READ MORE <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="section">
            <tr>
                <td>item 211</td>
                <td>item 212</td>
                <td>item 213</td>
                <td>item 214</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>item 221</td>
                <td>item 222</td>
                <td>item 223</td>
                <td>item 224</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>item 231</td>
                <td>item 232</td>
                <td>item 233</td>
                <td>item 234</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6" class="flip">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/logosquare-big.png" /><button>PLAY NOW!</button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div>200% UP TO</div>
                                <div>$1000</div>
                                <div>+250 FREE SPINS</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-nodeposit.png" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="readmore" id="acc1">READ MORE <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="section">
            <tr>
                <td>item 311</td>
                <td>item 312</td>
                <td>item 313</td>
                <td>item 314</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>item 321</td>
                <td>item 322</td>
                <td>item 323</td>
                <td>item 324</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>item 331</td>
                <td>item 332</td>
                <td>item 333</td>
                <td>item 334</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6" class="flip">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/logosquare-big.png" /><button>PLAY NOW!</button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div>200% UP TO</div>
                                <div>$1000</div>
                                <div>+250 FREE SPINS</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-deposit.png" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star-half fa-2x"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="readmore" id="acc1">READ MORE <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="section">
            <tr>
                <td>item 311</td>
                <td>item 312</td>
                <td>item 313</td>
                <td>item 314</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>item 321</td>
                <td>item 322</td>
                <td>item 323</td>
                <td>item 324</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>item 331</td>
                <td>item 332</td>
                <td>item 333</td>
                <td>item 334</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6" class="flip">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/logosquare-big.png" /><button>PLAY NOW!</button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div>200% UP TO</div>
                                <div>$1000</div>
                                <div>+250 FREE SPINS</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-check.png" /> sfgfsjghsjghsjghjsghsjghsj
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <img src="http://freespins.dev.kim/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-nodeposit.png" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="readmore" id="acc1">READ MORE <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="section">
            <tr>
                <td>item 311</td>
                <td>item 312</td>
                <td>item 313</td>
                <td>item 314</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>item 321</td>
                <td>item 322</td>
                <td>item 323</td>
                <td>item 324</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>item 331</td>
                <td>item 332</td>
                <td>item 333</td>
                <td>item 334</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery code

```
$('button').click(function() {
      $(this).parents('tr')
        .closest('tbody')
        .next('.section')
        .toggle('slow');
    });
 });
```

Please edit your code like above.

Also look at working example

https://jsfiddle.net/bilawalkhan/2d1y1592/

Hope this would be helpful. Thanks